# Converting real-time audio to phonemes

Tags: javascript, python, speech-recognition, phoneme

Using a microphone as an input for real-time audio. How do I extract the currently said phoneme from the audio?
I need it for lipsyncing 2d characters.

Basically, my approach would be to:

1. Fetch the real-time audio using a microphone
2. Detect the current phoneme that is being pronounced from the audio.

I have tried looking everywhere for an example or library that could solve this type of problem. Most libraries don't seem to output phonemes from audio.

There is a website that explains how they used machine learning to solve this, however without any code or tutorial on how to do it. https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1910.08685/

There is also this cool speech recognition tool called Pocketsphinx, but I cannot seem to find an example of it using Phoneme Recognition yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to get the *word* from the audio using Whisper or a similar STT service (the Python [Speech Recognition Library](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) is the go-to at the moment), *then* I would use the [CMU Dict Library](https://pypi.org/project/cmudict/) to provide phonemes for each word.

The phonemes are given using the CMU dictionary - for example `DH` for the `θ` phoneme - the `th` sound in `this` and `that`. That is, they are *not* given in IPA pronunciation - so you may need another layer if you need the phonemes in IPA format. If you need IPA formatted phonemes, then consider the [IPA2 library](https://github.com/voidful/ipa2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Managed to achieve (somewhat) real-time Speech-To-Phonemes by transcribing streaming audio, whilst splitting the words into it's different phonemes. While it isn't (entirely) real-time, a 300ms delay should suffice :)

Comment: You're welcome! Interesting project, and good luck with it.